# Problemas con la validacion de codigo con mis usuarios

Tags: mysql, jquery, ajax, email, validación

**Saludos estoy trabajando en una pagina we, en el cual registro participantes con su correo, estoy tratando de validar cuando tengo un correo exitente en la base de datos salga la ventana de alert que ya a sido registraodo, pero resulta que ya no peudo registrar nunguno, y no logro ver mi error.
Si me pudieran orientar estaria agradecido. **

```js
$(function() {
  $("#form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/insert.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(result) {
        if (result) {
          console.log("entra");
          $("#modal").modal("show");
        } else {
          alert("EL correo ya fue proporcionado, ingrese otro de favor");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
**Este es mi archivo de insercion de datos, y aqui si se encunetra un row igual regresa un 0 pero si no hace la insercioin nyu regresa un 1. **
<?php

include "conexion.php";
$link=conectarse();

$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$correo=$_POST['email'];
$nomagui=$_POST['noma'];
$desc1=$_POST['desc1'];
$archi=$_POST['archi'];
$desc2=$_POST['desc2'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE Correo='$correo'";
 $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
 $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 if($num_rows){
  return 0;
 }else{
  mysqli_query($link, "insert into info(Correo, Nombre, NombreAgui, DescNom, ArchDib, DescDib) values('$correo','$nombre','$nomagui','$desc1','$archi','$desc2')") or die(mysqli_error($link));
  return 1;
 }


mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Puedes imprimir el error porfa. Para ver qué error te marca.

Comment: CAlro nada mas que en el inspector no me sale ningun error, nada mas este o no este el correo no me deja insertar el registro. Y en la funcion  de jquary no entre el modal si no salta al alert en el if.

Comment: La evaluación que haces es poco clara: `if($num_rows){ return 0; }else{ //... }` Debes poner algo más específico como: **`if($num_rows===0){ //lo que hay que hacer si no se encuentran filas }else{ //Lo que hay que hacer si se encuentran filas }`**

Comment: Saludos, ya le pregunte a un Compañero, ya me dijo el error, resulta que estaba mandando desde mi php el resuldato, me menciono que cambiara el return por un echo y despues en mi ajax resulta que el result era una cadena por que estaba validadon el correo y puse en el if parseint(result) que lo que hace es que el result aun quesea una cadena, tome el valor de enteros, que en este caso lo que imprimo es 1 o 0.